Installation Issues with Ubuntu 24.04: System Error and Bootable Drive Creation Failures
I'm trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 but encountering several issues:
System Error During Installation: When I attempt to install Ubuntu 24.04, I encounter a system error. The installation window either can't stay open or fails to load properly. Each time I reopen the window, it closes before it can even fully load. Despite having all the necessary system requirements for the installation, the process keeps failing.
Bootable Drive Creation Issue with Balena Etcher: I've tried creating a bootable drive using Balena Etcher, but I get an error when selecting the ISO file I downloaded from the official Ubuntu website. This is preventing me from even starting the installation process.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please read How do I ask a good question? And provide us more details. Edit your question and include the system error you are encountering.

I ran into some similar issues while trying to install Ubuntu 24.04, so I totally understand your frustration. Here are a few things you could try:

Check the ISO: First off, make sure the ISO you downloaded isn’t corrupted. You can verify its integrity by checking the SHA256 checksum against what’s listed on the Ubuntu site.

Switch Up Your USB Tool: If Balena Etcher is giving you a hard time, maybe try a different tool like Rufus (if you’re on Windows) or use the dd command if you’re on Linux. Sometimes, different tools handle the ISO in different ways.

Different USB Drive: If you have another USB stick lying around, give that a shot. Some USB drives just don’t play nice with certain installations.

BIOS/UEFI Settings: Make sure to check your BIOS/UEFI settings. It might help to disable Secure Boot and enable Legacy Boot if you’re on UEFI. That can sometimes smooth out the installation process.

Try Another Machine: If you can, test the USB drive on another computer. This can help you see if it’s a hardware issue or something specific to your setup.

Hardware Compatibility: Double-check that your hardware is compatible with Ubuntu 24.04. Sometimes newer hardware can cause hiccups.

Look for Logs: If the installer keeps crashing, see if you can access any installation logs. They might give you some clues about what’s going wrong.


I hope one of these suggestions helps you out! If you figure out the issue, definitely share what worked for you—it could save someone else the same headache!
